# Optional Multiple entry on a jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Hey i'm working on a form that need to be submitted on my jsp page. In one of the fields i need an optional mulitple entry in the form of a plus mark. i.e if the user wants to having multiple entries into this text box he clicks on the plus sign and then he enters the information.Can someone point me in the right direction on how to go about solving this problem?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

try this code I think it may solve your problem : 
html :

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;
                return false;
        });

        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
```

result : 
http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tzpg4/4/